# How to draw a barrel or a circle in WPF Viewport3D?

Tags: c#, wpf, viewport3d

I have a `WPF` project that contains a 3D models. I did search a lot about `Viewport3D` but didn't found any helpful results to draw a barrel in 3D.
Also the `Camera` move is kinda bad, how can I edit it too?

Comment: With WPF/Viewport3D you should create a MeshGeometry3D which contains the vertices/normals and triangles, and place it inside a ModelVisual3D (which contains also the material).  [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-apply-multiple-transformations-to-a-3-d-model?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) is an example.

Comment: Thank You For Answer 

I've already saw that example before but it's not what I'm looking for.
But I need to move it with mouse, I know how to draw a square or a circle but I have no idea about the barrel. Is there any way which I can draw the barrel? do you have any good tutorials about it?

Comment: You need a model of a barrel. You could use rotation of the camera with your mouse. [How to rotate camera in ViewPort3D using mouse in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049959/how-to-rotate-camera-in-viewport3d-using-mouse-in-wpf)